# Electron Angular playing static audio files

Tags: angular, audio, electron

I try to develop a native app using electron and angular2.
Its purpose is to conduct Psychology experiments connected with sound perception.

In order to do this, I want to play sounds that will be stored in some assets directory in my app directories. But I find difficulties with accessing those audio files from angular in order to play it. And the internet seems to be pretty unhelpful after half day of searching I did not find and supporting articles.

What is the best way to do it?

Should I add to my app some server application, with angular proxying api requests to it? That solution will most likely work accordingly to what I found.

But is there any simple solution? Like some Electron library that allows offline access from Angular level to file system and files that are in app directory?

Thanks in advance
Tomasz

Comment: Can you give us some more info on exactly what you've tried so far to play these sounds? If you post some code we can try and work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [howler.js](http://howlerjs.com)
You can install it to your project with `npm install --save howler` and play a sound with

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sound.mp3']
});

sound.play();
```

You would also probably want to install `@types/howler` via npm to work with typescript

Comment: The problem is how to load files.  The audio api expect a an http url. Or a relative path. Which will be resolved to an http request. Also it can expect a data URL. But it will be nice if we can give it the files as in `file://path.wav`